# lower_bound complexity of associative container: member function vs non-member function

Tags: c++

*set* and *map* have *lower_bound* (as well as *upper_bound* and *equal_range*) member function with Log(N) time complexity. There is also non-member *lower_bound* which is available by including *algorithm* header. As per description non-member function's complexity is Log(N) for random access iterators and linear otherwise. *set* and *map* iterators are not random access. Does it mean I should avoid non-member function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) is meant to be used on an sorted range defined by a pair of iterators, typically `begin` and `end` from some container. If you use it with the bidirectional (non-random-access) iterators from `std::set` or `std::map`, then it will have to traverse the range linearly, unlike with random-access iterators. The methods [`std::set::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) and [`std::map::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) exist because it can take advantage of the internal structure of the container to perform better than its free function counterpart. So yes, indeed, you should favor this method when working with `std::set` or `std::map`, if you can.

Comment: This generally goes for all containers, when there's a member version of an algorithm it's for good reason and you should use that one instead of the non-member version.